# What's a clean sans font that supports UTF-8, that is suitable for console use?

Tags: fonts, unicode

I'm looking for a font for my console that supports the more unique utf-8 characters. (like ► λ ✔ ✓ ✘ ✢ ➤ ✖ ❯ ❮ ✚ ✹ ➜ ═ ✭).

Despite some googling, I haven't been able to find a font that I like. Any suggestions?

I am using mintty through cygwin on windows as well as terminal on ubuntu.

Comment: You need to define "console".  What's appropriate/usable for _a GUI terminal emulator that uses X_ is different to what's appropriate/usable for [_a user-space virtual terminal_](http://askubuntu.com/a/705853/43344), which is in turn different to what's appropriate/usable for _a kernel virtual terminal_.

Comment: @JdeBP - that depends, of course, on the *user-space virtual terminal*.  at least one user-space linux console replacement is X-font friendly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been using [DejaVu Sans Mono](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/Main_Page) for all my console stuff (Cygwin, PuTTY/KiTTY, ConEmu) for a good while now, and can recommend.